# Как исправить ошибку с telegram widgets?

Tags: django, telegram

Все привет. На своем сайте планирую сделать регистрацию через телеграм.

Проблема в том, что перенаправление на нужный url после регистрации работает только на firefox. На других же браузерах ничего не работает(chrome, yandex). В чем может быть проблема?